# Import in SAS : characters seen as date

Tags: sas

I would like to import a csv database with the following statement:

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= WORK.claims 
DATAFILE= database.csv'
DBMS=csv REPLACE;
DELIMITER=",";
GETNAMES=YES;       
RUN;
```

The problem is that I have a variable of the form  " 25/10/2013abcedfg:1234 " that I would like to treat as a characters string. But SAS sees it like a date, and put the date format. Then I get an error message because it is of course not a date.

Would you have a solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `infile` to read in the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just don't rely on PROC IMPORT and write your import in data step.
PROC IMPORT should generate its import datastep in your log, use that and adjust it.

Comment: This is the best way.  When you run PROC IMPORT, it writes some code for you (wrong code, but code none-the-less).  Use "Run->Recall Last Submit" if you are in the SAS IDE.  This will put the PROC IMPORT code into the current text editor.  Then adjust the type, informat, etc. of the variable that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of PROC IMPORT, use an input statement

```
DATA WORK.claims;
format crazyvar $25 obs_num this_value 8.;
infile "database.csv" lrecl = 500 /** Number of columns you'll need **/ 
pad = end /** Prevents truncation **/
dsd delimiter = ',' /**Delimiter Sensitive Data, and sets delimiter to comma **/ ; 
input obs_num crazyvar $ this_value;
run;
```

Concur with Vasja, PROC IMPORT has its uses but it's not always sensitive to the type of data you're trying to read in. Natively it reads in a certain number of rows (I think the first 20 by default) and guesses what type of variable it is.

If you need to use PROC IMPORT, you can set the GUESSINGROWS parameter higher to give the procedure a more educated guess.